# Suggestion to improve questions sorting

Tags: feature-request

When I'm looking for questions I'd like to see Unanswered, with most votes filtered by tags (possible exclusions) recent questions first.

In other words I'd like to have custom order of the questions. Currently provided few choices looks strange for me (what is Hot or Interesting?) and a little frustarting. For example, I choose Newest and when I see that all of them are answered and click for next page I have more newest so my next page starts in the middle of previous and I continue to read the same answered questions.

So, at least pagination should continue from current point and not always from scratch.

Another example would be Most Voted - on top I see questions with votes for year 2010 which where already answered. How does it help me to find question which I can help with?

Bottom line - what I want and what will do my life much easier - just one feature - **allow to filter Unanswered Question view for some period of time**. For example one week. In this case I can see most voted/interesting/hot question for my expertise which are not few years old and relevant for OP.

**Addition:**
Thanks for @Kendra now I know how to search interesting for me questions. 
Here is search string:

```
[java] score:2 answers:..0 created:2d.. isanswered:0 isaccepted:0 duplicate:0 locked:0
```

It works good but I still have a lot of unwanted results like questions closed, duplicated, on hold. Is there way to exclude them from the results?
Something like this (I also included filtering **out** tag [javascript]):

```
[java] ^[javascript] hold:NO closed:NO score:2 answers:..0 created:2d.. isanswered:0 isaccepted:0 duplicate:0 locked:0
```

Comment: You can do a lot with the unanswered button and/or advanced search but what in the world is `with most votes filtered by tags recent questions first`.  Do you want most votes or recent?

Comment: Most people searching are looking for questions that have answers (so they can solve a problem). Your suggestion is very unclear, because you're confusing "most voted" and "unanswered". Questions that have been around long enough to be among the most voted are highly likely to have answers, so you're asking for opposing things at the same time - "unanswered" plus "not here long" plus "highest voted".

Comment: I think SO is the best site. Whenever I search for knowledge and see link to SO I use it first. But, that's for knowledge searchers. For those who want to share knowledge SO process is not such convenient and I gave some examples of such inconvenience. I want to search questions which are important (more votes could be on unanswered question), recent (not couple years ago) and those which I can answer (tags positive/negative filters). What is not fair with this? Of course I can live with current process but I had described what happens for me personally.I hope it could be the reason to improve

Comment: While it does not answer your question explicitly, you could always make a custom search string and bookmark it: `[your-tags] answers:0 created:6m.. score:3..` would give you a search in your selected tags, with 0 answers, created within the last six months, and with at least 3 score. You can then sort based on the normal search tabs. For other ways to customize this search string, see [the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)